# The rbd volumes config of rbd issue in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use the volumes rbd config to  mount the folder on ceph images . 
But it seems the container mount a host path.

I used the daemon of "https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/rbd".
The pod and container start successfully.

- I use the "docker exec " login the container and watch the /mnt folder.

  `root@test-rbd-read-01:/usr/local/tomcat# findmnt  /mnt

  TARGET SOURCE           FSTYPE OPTIONS
  /mnt   /dev/vda1[/var/lib/kubelet/pods/****/volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/rbd] xfs    rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
  root@test-rbd-read-01:/usr/local/tomcat# ls /mnt/
  root@test-rbd-read-01:/usr/local/tomcat#`
- And then I watch the host path that mount on the ceph. The `1.txt` had existed on ceph image.

  `[20:52 root@mongodb:/home] # mount |grep kubelet
  /dev/rbd0 on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/rbd/rbd/wujianlin-image-zlh_test type ext4 (ro,relatime,stripe=1024,data=ordered)
  /dev/rbd0 on /var/lib/kubelet/pods/****/volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/rbd type ext4 (ro,relatime,stripe=1024,data=ordered)
  [20:53 root@mongodb:/home] # ll /var/lib/kubelet/pods/****/volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/rbd
  total 20K
  drwx------ 2 root root 16K Mar 18 09:49 lost+found
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4 Mar 18 09:53 1.txt
  [20:53 root@mongodb:/home] # rbd showmapped
  id pool      image    snap device

  0  wujianlin zlh_test -    /dev/rbd0`

  **It should except that the container folder `/mnt` is same as the host path `/var/lib/kubelet/pods/ * * * */volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/rbd`, but it was not.**`

  **And I try to write file to /mnt, it also can not see any changes in `/var/lib/kubelet/pods/* * * */volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/rbd`**

  So is my some config wrong, or someting misunderstand ?

  k8s version: Release v1.2.0
  Here is my config:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-rbd-read-01
spec:
  containers:
  - name: tomcat-read-only-01
    image: tomcat
    volumeMounts:
    - name: rbd
      mountPath: /mnt
  volumes:
  - name: rbd
    rbd:
      monitors:
      - 10.63.90.177:6789
      pool: wujianlin
      image: zlh_test
      user: wujianlin
      secretRef:
        name: ceph-client-admin-keyring
      keyring: /etc/ceph/ceph.client.wujianlin.keyring
      fsType: ext4
      readOnly: true`

Comment: If restart the docker, the container can watch the file.

Answer (score 0):

what did you do when you restart docker? Are you able to reproduce this issue after the docker is restarted and pod is recreated?

Comment: Sorry for response so later. And thx for the response. I just do 'service restart docker', the mounted folder exit in old container.  But if you create a new container, the issue also exist.      In last days, I found it was an issue about systemd that will afffect the systemd config "mountFlag=true" in '/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service '